# In zsh how can I list all the environment variables?

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables

I want to get a list of all environment variables (shell variables? exported variables?) and their values at a given time, in zsh.
What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `typeset -x` or equivalently `export`, or `/usr/bin/env` (or just `env` if your `$PATH` is set right, i.e contains `/usr/bin:`)

Comment: If you use `zsh` shell, I would recommend installing these plugins: `alias-finder` , `aliases`. To install append the mentioned plugin names in `~/.zshrc` to the line describing plugins.

Comment: `env` and `export` are alsoe good options when combined with `grep` like this `export | grep "git"`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It sounds like you want `env`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The `HOST` env is missing from the output of `env`.   On zsh I was able to list everything with `set`.

Comment: @Chris If `$HOST` is missing from env, then it's not an environment variable.

Comment: @ Chris (nice name!).  Where's `echo $HOST` coming from?  Is this some sort of zsh variable that's not an actual OS environment variable?  For my purposes `$HOST` exists and has the value I want, but it only appears in `set` and not `env`.

Comment: @Chris `$HOST` is a zsh variable instantiated on startup which is not exported by default. Most variables are not environment variables unless you explicitly `export` them. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HOST

Answer (score 43):

`export` prints out the list of environment variables and their values. The values are quoted, the output of `export` is suitable for reading back into the shell. The variables are printed in alphabetical order.

If you want shell variables as well, use `set`. If you want shell variables with type annotations (`exported`, `integer`, etc.), use `typeset`.

You can use `export` and `set` on other shells as well, but most don't quote the output, so it's not parseable. `typeset` is available (with different behavior) on ksh and bash.

If you want the environment variables, there's also the `env` command, which prints unsorted, unquoted

If you only want the names, access the `parameters` associative array. The keys are the parameter names and the values indicate the types.

Comment: Some difference with `env`: `env -i '$(reboot)=1' zsh -c export` (compare with `bash` where you don't want to feed it back into the shell (fixed in 4.4)). And `env -i zsh 'export foo; export'`. See also http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01840.html and the `env -i zsh -c export` bug in recent versions of zsh which I've just reported.

Comment: See also [`typeset -p +H -m '*'`](/a/117344) to list all variables, including hidden ones.