# How can I list all shell variables?

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables

Reading about this question: [In zsh how can I list all the environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30751/in-zsh-how-can-i-list-all-the-environment-variables/30813?noredirect=1#comment290611_30813), I wondered, how can I list all the **shell variables**?

Also, does the distinction between **shell** variables and **environment** variables apply to shells other than zsh?

I am primarily interested in Bash and Zsh, but it would be great to know how to do this in other mainstream shells.

Comment: A general warning related to most methods: When using such things in scripts, beware variables whose value contains a newline, e.g. IFS. Their representation in the output may span multiple lines.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### List all shell variables

**`bash`** : use `set -o posix ; set`. The `posix` option avoids outputting too much information, like function definitions. `declare -p` also works.

**`zsh`** : use `typeset`.

### Shell variables and environment variables

An environment variable is available to `exec()`-ed child processes (as a copy; if parent process change the variable, the child environment is not updated). A non-environment variable is only available to the current running shell and `fork()`-ed subshells. This distinction is present in all shells.

Comment: The question also has an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305237/how-to-list-variables-declared-in-script-in-bash

Comment: `set -o posix` doesn't exist in zsh; `set` doesn't output function definitions.

Comment: `set -o posix` is a syntax error in most shells.

Comment: Shell variables are also available in child processes. The difference comes when the child process executes a new program: environment variables are passed along in `exec`, shell variables are not.

Comment: @Barmar if shell variable are not passed, then their content is not available in child processes, no ?

Comment: When a process forks, all its memory is duplicated. This includes shell variables. They're not lost until the child process calls `exec` to run an external program. Then only environment variables are passed.

Comment: Try: `var=1; (set)`. The parentheses fork a subshell. You'll see `var=1` in the output.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, that is an interesting case. I cannot find other situations where there is no `exec()` after the original shell `fork()`s, that's why I made the shorcut about availability of environment variables. You have other cases like this in mind ?

Comment: I'm just trying to make the answer more accurate. For the purposes of contrasting shell variables with environment variables, it's important to distinguish between forking and execing.

Comment: In bash: `declare -px` or simply `declare -x` will print only exported variables.

Answer (score 19):

There are many alternatives:

**printenv**

> Print  the  values of the specified environment VARIABLE(s).  If no VARIABLE is specified, print name and value pairs for them all.

**env**

> env - run a program in a modified environment

**export**

> Set an environment variable. Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment.....
>
> -p   Display output in a form that may be reused as input.
>
> If no names are supplied, or if the `-p' option is given, a list of exported names is displayed.

**set**

is useful to get shell variables as well.

If you need extra info (integer, exported) you should instead use

**typeset**

*export* has an advantage, that its output can be immediately read back onto the shell.

Lastly, there is

**compgen -v**

> Display possible completions depending on the options.

which shows all variables, shell and environment, without their value or extra info. You will have to *echo $VARIABLE_NAME* to find the variable value. But at least the list is complete. It belongs to *bash*, not *zsh*.

Comment: `export` has no advantage over `set`, at least, when it comes to quoting for shell re-entry. And `printenv` and `env` are not at all about shell variables, though these do often coincide with environment variables.

Comment: `compgen -e` displays only exported shell variables. Details and other options in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151120/119895).

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`, you can use `typeset`, which gives more information than `set`, e.g. the type of the variables. You can still filter the output with `grep` or `sed`, depending on what you want. Environment variables are marked as `exported` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I had just needed listing only the variables, not their values.
For this, I used

```
env | awk -F '=' '{ print $1 }'
```

To have all of them in a single line

```
env | awk -F '=' '{ print $1 }' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: OP was asking about the "shell variables" rather than the environment variables.  Your info about how to only show the variable names is a useful addition to the discussion.  `set -o posix ; set | awk -F '=' '{ print $1 }'` would be just the shell variable names.  

Thanks!